# Can I turn an SSH dynamic port forward to a VPN to use for the whole system?

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding, socks-proxy

I can create a socks proxy with ssh dynamic port forwarding and set my web browser to use it, but I want to use that route for the whole system. Is there a way for doing that? Can I turn that socks proxy to a VPN connection somehow?

Comment: I haven't done anything like it before but this seems to cover that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN  "You must be using OpenSSH version 4.3 or later".  and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH    I've heard it can be done but i've got no idea really. Just thought those two links might help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested this and it worked: https://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/tun2socks

It seems that Proxifiers are for this purpose too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers

HTH anyone reading this topic in the future.